# Looping hair with a jumping animation

Tags: animation, hair

I'm using hair dynamics for my particle hair to animate a short 60 frame jumping animation. I'd like to have the hair be at the same location from the first frame to the last frame for looping purposes.
I tried different simulation start and end points,
Tripling frame count from 60 to 180 and using the simulations from 120-180,
but they all appear slightly different.
Any tips? Thanks

Comment: you could do this with a mesh cache. Export your hair as a point cache 2 times. Then use meshcache influence to interpolate between them.

Comment: So point cache is the same one as baking on hair dynamics right? So I bake them twice, and insert those into the mesh cache modifier? Do I need to make two mesh cache modifiers?

Comment: @Chris Good idea. For someone who never did that a proper answer how to do this would be great :)

Comment: @Search: exactly. So you "bake" (export pointcache -> you have to enable the add-on for that) just the two "slightly" different hair "frames", then give two cache modifiers...i think even one is enough...because it changes then from your "slightly" different to your loop start as you want it. Baking is normally multiple frames -> pointcache has just one frame ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I might be doing something wrong. Baking the cache > Export as .pc2 using the add-on > add MeshCache modifier on the hair > File format is pc2 > File path is the exported .pc2 file > influence set to 1.0 > Turn off hair dynamics > and if I start the animation there is no movement.Hair particles stay on the head but my scalp object shifts to a weird location away from the head.